# ¿Como hacer una clave compuesta y usarla como foreign SQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada `properties`, con una llave compuesta por un campo int llamado `property_type_id`, y un campo varchar llamado `name`, no tengo muy claro como debería usarla como foránea en otra tabla, debería tener una columna (en la tabla foranea) por columna (en la tabla properties) que componga la llave compuesta? O en una sola columna puedo guardar toda la llave compuesta?

Comment: Porque la clave es compuesta? es es raro.. vos podrias tener dos property_type_id con distinto nombre? no deberia haber otro id que sea la clave?

Comment: La idea de la clave compuesta es debido a que no debería existir una combinación donde name=A-101 y property_type_id=1 se puedan repetir

Comment: Eso quiere decir que estas relegando una regla de negocio (que es que eso no se pueda repetir) y le estas diciendo a la DB que lo controle.. en lugar de que lo controle el programa que ingresa los datos. Ojo con repartir las reglas de negocios, que despues no se saben donde estan (no esta mal)...

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, la verdad lo había pensado totalmente al contrario, es decir, pensé que eso lo debía validar la base de datos y no el programa, pero pensándolo mejor tienes razón, en todo caso, la forma de hacer llaves foráneas con compuestas es algo que tal vez pueda servirme en un futuro

Comment: @gbianchi yo creo que es totalmente normal controlar eso a nivel de BBDD, porque además no es muy difícil. Eso no quita que se controle también en otras capas, pero a nivel de BBDD es casi gratis hacerlo.

Comment: @Marc lo podemos discutir bastante.. pero gratis??? estas repartiendo reglas de negocios en tu db (yo por mi parte, no pongo nada, pero nada en la db). Despues gratis no es.. implica generar un try catch del lado del programa, revisar por un tipo de error especifico, avisarlo despues que el usuario hizo el insert. Ni hablar de si esto esta en una transaccion. No es mas facil controlar todo antes? Igual.. ya lo dije.. mal no esta.. pero es dudoso...

Comment: Pues yo hago al revés, en general me resulta muy fácil modelar la BBDD e incluir este tipo de restricciones, después en el código los try catch ya los incluyes por otras cosas (que no haya conexión por ejemplo)... no se, a mi me parece casi gratis. Igual he conocido otros desarrolladores de tu opinión, así que tampoco me parece raro. Supongo que depende mucho de las costumbres que uno va adquiriendo con el tiempo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Básicamente tienes 2 opciones:

1. La que tu comentas, es decir crear dos columnas `property_type_id` y `name` en la tabla foránea. Este modelo se puede complicar rápidamente.
2. En tu tabla con la llave compuesta, creas una tercera columna, como una llave adicional a la existente (por ejemplo `property_id`) y esta la recreas en la tabla foránea y la usas como clave foránea.

Cuando usar uno u otro caso depende mucho de las circunstancias (aunque como apunta gbiachi en los comentarios la primera opción en general es siempre desaconsejable) pero diría que con el segundo caso no se tiende a complicar tanto el modelo.

En concreto, tu tienes una tabla `properties` que tiene como llave 2 campos. Esa llave de 2 campos asegura:

> Que no existe mas que una combinación de valores de ambos campos... o dicho de otra manera para 'property_type_id' y 'name' concretos identificamos univocamente un registro de 'properties'

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero si tienes que utilizar esa combinación como clave foranea, tienes que crear esos campos en la nueva tabla, donde además es muy probable que tambien pasen a formar parte de la llave que tenga que tener la nueva tabla... y si a su vez esta nueva llave (de al menos 2 campos) tiene que se clave foranea en otra tabla ... en fin, que se complica todo excesivamente.

Si en cambio en la tabla `properties` te creas un campo `property_id` y lo conviertes en llave (o clave), tendrás la tabla con dos llaves, una compuestas de los dos campos originales (que por el hecho de ser llave seguirán cumpliendo la condición de no repetirse) y una llave adicional que es la que podrás utilizar como clave foránea en otras tablas, quedando el modelo más sencillo.

Habitualmente, una de las dos llaves que creas en la tabla, deberás considerarla como primaria y en este ejemplo debería ser `property_id` así la otra llave simplemente se queda para asegurar que no se repite una pareja de 'property_type_id' y 'name'.

Comment: +1. igual usar la opcion 1 deberia ser siempre un NO NO...

Comment: Podrías explicarme la segunda opción que me comentas, de una forma mas especifica?

Comment: Ok te edito la respuesta para hacerla más clara

Comment: Muchas gracias, he entendido y ya se que debo hacer